# How would you TDD or unit test a class/method that shutsdown an NT Service like "telnet"?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

New to unit testing and TDD and I write alot more OS utilities than say traditional LOBs.  So, I understand how you might mock or stub a database or a file, but how about things like:

- Authentication against Active Directory
- Stopping an NT service
- Authorization against an AD Group
- etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot test whether a service was actually stopped using unit test. That's what other tests (e.g. integration tests) are for. Often it is worth testing though, whether you system under test (SUT) is actually making the right calls to stop the service.

In that case could wrap these concrete APIs into an interface (façade) specifically tailored towards the needs of your consumers. And then mock that interface and assert that the appropiate members have been called with the right arguments by your consumers that you are testing.

Example (c#, NUnit, FakeItEasy):

```
// implementation of this interface basically wraps the concrete service APIs of the OS
public interface IServiceController
{
   public void Start(string serviceName);  
   public void Stop(string serviceName);
}    

// consumer that wants to stop a specific service and that is your SUT
public class SomeConsumer
{
    // ctor takes dependency on a service controller
    SomeConsumer(IServiceController controller)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public void DoSomethingThatRequiresAServiceStop()
    {
       // ...
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SomeConsumerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void DoSomethingThatRequiresAServiceStop_StopsServiceXYZ()
    {
          // arrange
          IServiceController mockServiceConntroler = A.Fake<IServiceController>();
          SomeConsumer sut = new SomeConsumer(mockServiceController);

         // act
         sut.DoSomethingThatRequiresAServiceStop();

         // assert
         A.CallTo(() => mockServiceConntroler.Stop("XYZ")).MustHaveHappend();
    }
}
```

[As Matt already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280475/4227) in some environments that are tools that allow you to replace concrete implementations without you having to introduce abstractions (here: `IServiceController`). I tend to avoid these as much as possible because they often are not only a bit tedious to use but also seem to enforce bad design choice (e.g. depending on concrete implementations instead of abstractions). I see tools like Microsoft Moles or TypeMock Isolator more as tools that help you work with legacy code bases that already have a ton of bad design choices that you cannot get rid of (right away).

Comment: +1 for noting Mocking frameworks that instrument the code under test rather than stubbing (Moles, TypeMock).

Comment: The usage of FakeItEasy in this example is not quite correct, the "MustHaveHappened"-part should be last in the test as an assertion. MustHaveHappened is an assertion, not the set up of an expectation.

Answer (score 2):

With some code it may not be possible to unit test with stubs or mocks *directly* in a loosely coupled way* as the code you are depending on itself may not be loosely coupled. You may need to end up writing an integration test instead.

If this is the case, it may be better to **write a wrapper class** (i.e. use the [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern) over the non-unit-testable code driven by integration tests. This way you can still stub/mock your wrapper class elsewhere in the code using unit tests when you need to, say, start/stop a windows service. Your wrapper class also is test-driven, but just with integration tests instead.

*<sub>If on .NET some tools out there may allow you to still write unit tests and inject some sort of fake object, such as Microsoft Moles (soon to be named Fakes) or TypeMock Isolator in these cases, but the tests would be slower and take more code to write. While I've used Moles, I personally would rather wrap the hard-to-test code instead of using these tools.</sub>